# Injecting datasource in EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

When you inject a datasource in your application and get a connection by invoking `getConnection()` on it, are you supposed to close the connection?

Comment: Yes you need to close the connection which will release the connection back to the pool.

Comment: Why do you want to use getConnection and not injecting the PersistenceContext directly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Even though the datasource itself is container managed, the API indeed requires the programmer to close connections. This is different from a couple of other container managed resources (like the entity manager), where the container takes care of closing. Note that closing here in the majority of cases doesn't *actually* closes the connection here, but returns the connection to a connection pool.

As a rule of thumb, if you use a factory-ish resources to obtain one or more other resources from that can be closed, you have to close them. Otherwise the container does this.

Since [Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) implements [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), you can use a try-with-resources block for this:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/app/datasource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void doStuff() {
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {

            // Work with connection here

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new SomeRuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Of course, otherwise you'll exhaust your connection pool. It's best to do this in finally block:

```
@Resource(mappedName="jndi/yourDatasource")
DataSource ds;

..

Connection conn = null;
try {
     conn = ds.getConnection();
     //PERFORM QUERY, ETC..
}
catch(SQLException ex) {
     //EXCEPTION HANDLING
}
finally {
    try {
        if(conn != null)
            conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {..}
}
```